# Edge triggers fail when an XmlHttpRequest is aborted

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge, jqxhr

I was testing a tool that fires some asynchronous ajax requests. The response of one request can abort another one. This works great as far as I have tested this (Chrome, Firefox) but Edge doesn't like aborting! As soon as the XmlHttpRequest is blocked, Edge throws a fail - which I wish not to happen.

This is the code (that gets aborted by another snippet):

```
  xhr = $.ajax("my-url.php")
    .done(function(json) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(json);
        if (data.data) {
           // Yay data!
        } else {
            // Ahw no data or empty data
        }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        // This is triggered by Edge, `error` is "abort"
        var string = "An error occurred: " + error + ".";
        alert(string);
    })
    .always(function() {
        done = true;
    });
```

So, the result is an alert *An error occurred: abort.* Question one: **why** is Edge doing this? Does it handle XHR in a different way than other browsers? What is the standard? Secondly, how do I make sure I do not show this message? Can I simply do something like this in `fail()`, or isn't that a pretty way of going about this:

```
if (error != 'abort') {
  // Do stuff, only when error isn't abort
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found what happens.
This is my code (copied from yours):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';
        var xhr, done;
        function getResp() {
            if (!done && xhr && xhr.readyState !== 4)
                xhr.abort();
            done = false;
            xhr = $.ajax("json.php",{method:'GET'}) 
// you didn't include method so method is 'GET'
// when I change it to 'POST' Edge honors xhr.abort()
                .done(function (json) {
                    console.log(json);
                    var data = $.parseJSON(json);
                    if (data.data) {
                        // Yay data!
                    } else {
                        // Ahw no data or empty data
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                    // This is triggered by Edge, `error` is "abort"
                    var string = "An error occurred: " + error + ".";
                    //alert(string);
                    console.log(string);
                })
                .always(function () {
                    done = true;
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="getResp()" value="run" />
</body>
</html>
```

and my php:

```
<?php
usleep(10000000); //10 seconds
echo '{"name":"test","qty":10,"curr":"'.date('h:i:s').'"}';
?>
```

General answer: Edge caches xhr `GET` response and returns data immediately. FF sends request to the server. It makes all difference.
`POST` requests aren't cached and `xhr.abort()` produces expected result in all browsers.
Is it acceptable answer?